# WPF assign Z-Order of owned windows without changing focus

Tags: wpf, user-interface, focus, window

Due to OpenGL airspace issues I have several windows that are owned by the main window but look and act like controls.   I also have some data readout/sort windows that show real-time data and need to be normal floating windows,  also owned by the main window so that they remain floating above the main window even while operations are performed in the main window.

The issue: 
I open a data readout window (normal window) and am watching data change.  Then I click on a text box to enter a value in one of the windows that acts as a control due to airspace issues, and it becomes activated, covering up my data readout window.  This is bad because the airspace window is supposed to act like it is part of the main window.   I tried some tricks with Activation and Deactivation, and it looks ok but then editing the airspace window at all is impossible because WPF only lets me edit the activated window.

How can I ask that normal data readout window to please stay above all other windows owned by the main window, but still let other windows receive focus?

Comment: Are you using WindowsFormsHost to place the OpenGL windows in your View?

Answer (score 1):

There's a [recent article](http://blogs.msdn.com/visualstudio/archive/2010/03/23/wpf-in-visual-studio-part-5-window-management.aspx) on the Visual Studio blog about how they do Window Management in the new WPF shell of Visual Studio. The section entitled "Auto-hide overlays" in the article talks about airspace issues and z-ordering. It might give you some hints.

Comment: The issues still exists in VS 2013:) Thanks for a very useful link!